# Convolve more than two vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`numpy.convolve` only convolves two vectors. I want to convolve a list of vectors:

`v1, v2, ..., vn`

Note that using the FFT it is possible to do the complete convolution much more efficiently than the naive:

`numpy.convolve(v1, numpy.convolve(v2, ...., numpy.convolve(vn-1, vn)...)`

Because you can FT each sequence once, and then invert FT the product of the transforms, which is more efficient.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you'll have to make the FFT calls yourself. [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve), the convolution function that actually uses an FFT, still only takes two inputs.